# Reverse click jquery

Tags: jquery

When I click on a class `.BOX-BTN`, my code adds a new class `.full` which adds an overlay. But when I click a second time, nothing happens and class remains active.

Upon the second click on `box-btn`, I want to return to the starting position, then on every click is changing class.

How can I achieve this?

```js
$(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.box-btn', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target).closest('.wrapper');
    target.find('.box-title, .box-text').addClass("full");
    target.find('.image-box').addClass("full-img");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead so it removes those classes on second click

```
target.find('.box-title, .box-text').toggleClass("full");
target.find('.image-box').toggleClass("full-img");
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how your code is structured, but changing `addClass` to `toggleClass` should do the trick

```
$(function($) {
      $(document).on('click', '.box-btn', function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target).closest('.wrapper');
        target.find('.box-title, .box-text').togleClass("full");
        target.find('.image-box').toggleClass("full-img");

      });
    });
```